# Any suggestions on "dragging" background image on IE10-11?

Tags: html, css, background-image

I have a footer that's a background-image and scrolls horizontally with the page. On IE10-11 the image sort of drags/smears. Of course it's fine in all other browsers.

Unfortunately, I can't share the dev site for client reasons but here is a short video of the problem. Sorry for the choppiness, but I think you can see the issue with the green part in the footer image. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1j7c8w378EzlSPknHAIGhfBnir546DmqU/view?usp=sharing

Here is the CSS for my footer:

```
#footer {
    height: 30%;
    background: transparent url(../img/footer.png) repeat-x;
    background-position-x: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: cover;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

And the JS:

```
$(document).on('scroll', (function() {
    // handles the scrolling of the footer
    $('#footer').css('background-position-x', -$(document).scrollTop());
}));
```

Comment: Nobody wants you to share the dev site. But chances are no one will be able to help without a [mcve]. You don't have to use the client's image to replicate the issue, do you?

Comment: Well the image in question is kind of specific. I went ahead and shared an old version of the site to see better. It's doing this dragging thing only on IE next to the tree on the right handed side, so i just used a screencast video since everybody might not have access to IE on Macs. I hope this is better.

Comment: It has more to do with JavaScript than CSS I guess. Have you checked the console? 

Also, the video you shared won''t run because it requires flash player on browser.

Comment: Just realized that. I uploaded to Google Drive and showed the JS for that section. Thanks and sorry for eveything not being clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're experiencing is IE's inability to properly render `.png` files with progressive transparency, also known as "the png bug".

There are several methods to fix it, all named "the png hack" or similar.

One of the most reliable and easy to apply is [the IE PNG fix](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/).

You can read more about this (and find alternative fixes) in this CSS Tricks [article](https://css-tricks.com/the-different-techniques-for-applying-the-png-hack/).
If possible for your example, giving up progressive transparency (saving in PNG-8 format) will likely help.

Comment: "The PNG Bug".....you are a god amongst men my friend. It's working in IE now.

I just noticed another issue on Android (Chrome) where the image just completely disappears instead of properly looping. Any ideas? I might just open another question since it's a different browser. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vBs3v93PB_ZSIzyYWfMeoDVd9Cf03lrK/view?usp=sharing